# what is the performance efficient method for iterate java collection?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I want to know about iterator design pattern and found on following tutorial.

http://www.journaldev.com/1716/iterator-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial

Following is the code for `hasNext()` and `next()` methods.

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    while (position < channels.size()) {
        Channel c = channels.get(position);
            if (c.getTYPE().equals(type) ||     type.equals(ChannelTypeEnum.ALL)) {
                return true;
            } else
                position++;
        }
    return false;
}

@Override
public Channel next() {
    Channel c = channels.get(position);
    position++;
    return c;
}
```

and using above method collection iterated is

```
while (baseIterator.hasNext()) {
    Channel c = baseIterator.next();
    System.out.println(c.toString());
}
```

If we are using `hasNext()` and `next()` methods it look like we are using while loop twice.

is this ok when application is small enough and performance is the priority? or there can be optimized code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of `Iterator` depends on its implementation. Every Java collection has its own iterator implementation, so the performance will vary. Usually `hasNext` and `next` methods have no loops. The code you are showing is some special iterator from the tutorial which iterates while performing the filtering. While you have two nested loops, you actually traverse the underlying collection `channels` only once as `position` constantly increases from 0 to `channels.size()`. The `hasNext()` internal loop is necessary to skip the unwanted items, but it does not add the computational difficulty. The overall difficulty of such iteration is `O(channels.size())`.

Note that this iterator implementation breaks the `Iterator` interface contract. First it does not throw `NoSuchElementException` at the end of the iteration. Second, if you call `next()` several times without calling `hasNext()` you will have different results. Thus I would not recommend use the samples from this tutorial in the real code.

Comment: Thanks @Tagir Valeev for explanations, now  I am really curious about how hasNext() and next() works in Java collection?

Comment: @AMY, check the Java source. For example, [here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#845) ArrayList iterator.

Comment: yes I gone through link you suggested. The code in hasNext() method "return cursor != size;" clears all doubts.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by "using while loop twice" ? if you are concerned whether you iterate twice over the collection, then it doesn't seem so to me.  the iterator keeps a position pointer that in both methods only seems to go forward. so while you do have nested loops (one in the application code, on in hasNext() method) they do not fetch the same item

Comment: Thanks @sharonbn, I got your point. The position pointer is keep go foreword and the while loop in hasNext() method not iterating completely.

Answer (score 0):

**Collections**

If `channels` are some kind of [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), then you can write the loop as

```
for(Channel c : channels) {
  if(c.getTYPE().equals(type) 
    || type.equals(ChannelTypeEnum.ALL)) {
       return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

No need to increment position if you're using that position only for iteration to the next element.

This is only shorthand - code for using an iterator as stated in comments - so it will not gain much in terms of performance but adds clarity to your code. Implementing your *own* iterator as you did in code above is not neccessary if the type of your `channels` already *is* a `Collection` and implements `Iterable`

Comment: this is just compiler shorthand for using iterator

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest way to iterate over a Set:

```java
int size = mySet.size();
Iterator<Integer> iteration = mySet.iterator();
for(int j = 0; j < size; j ++){
   doSomethingWith(iteration.next());
}
```

In this loop, you avoid the call to iteration.hasNext() with every step, which is why it is faster than the traditional iterator loop, and faster than the enhanced for-loop.

Of course, differences are very small, and you should optimize like this only if performance is really very important for your code.